# How to navigate from Login Page to Home Page in react native using react navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

i'm doing a small app in react native.I don't know much about react so please do help. I am trying react navigation.I want authenticated users to be redirect to home page.Don't know i've tried with stack navigator but not working.Following are the codes

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

    render(){
     const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
         login: { screen : LoginScreen },
         register: { screen : RegisterForm },

     )};

    return (

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <MainNavigator />
    </View>

    );
}
```

and the login screen

**LoginScreen.js**

```
  class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.initialState = {
                isLoading: false,
                error: null,
                username: '',
                password: '',           
            };
            this.state = this.initialState;
        }
   componentWillMount(){            
    fetch('https://www.mywebsite.com',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password,
                    client_id: 'xxxxx',
                    client_secret: 'xxxx',
                    callback_url: 'www.mywebsite.com'
                })

    })  
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {

            console.log(responseData);
          })    
       .done();
        }
        render(){
            return(


                                    <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")} >
                                        <Text style={{paddingLeft:50}}>Login</Text>
                                    </Button>
                      </View>
                     </View>                 
                   </Container>

            );
        }
    }
  export default LoginForm
```

also i am doing stack navigation for  rest of the screens.

**Route.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from './Profile';
import CourseListing from './CourseListing';
import Faq from './Faq';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import CategoryDetail from './CategoryDetail';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import DetailedView from './DetailedView';
import IndividualSection from './IndividualSection';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    LoginForm :{screen: LoginForm}
    CourseListing:{screen: CourseListing},
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    CategoryDetail: {screen: CategoryDetail},
    DetailedView: {screen: DetailedView},
    IndividualSection: {screen: IndividualSection}
})

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
     screen: StackScreens,
  },
  Profile: {
      screen: Profile
  },
  FAQ: {
      screen: Faq
  }
});
```

also i'm returning this `MyDrawer` component in `MyHome.js`

**MyHome.js**

```
class MyHome extends Component {


    render(){
        return(

        <MyDrawer />
        );
    }

}
export default MyHome;
```

So for now in `App.js` it will return `MainNavigator` which contains Login and Register screens. Also if i return `MyHome` instead of `MainNavigator`wihin `App.js` it will show the inner screens(without giving `LoginScreen` as stack in `Route.js`).But i want to navigate from login page to home page so how to do that??

Comment: try to read documentation first of [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating.html)

Comment: post your code with your error screenshot that would be helpful and mandatory to resolve issue on stackoverflow. By the way you are not importing or exporting the LoginScreen that what the error says

Comment: could you please post your route.js completely? I want to know what you are importing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i found a solution for this.I done this using nested navigator.Defined `MainNavigator` in `App.js` within `Route.js`. Now i'm able to navigate from login screen to home screen